Squash merging a PR on GitHub with clean commit history
When working with GitHub and the likes, I tend to work on a feature branch, where I frequently commit & push changes; about as frequently as I locally save the files I'm editing. This is quite useful for various reasons, but it does mean that my commits are quite random and writing good commit messages for all of them is a waste of time. After I'm done, I create a PR with a proper commit message and after any potential review, I squash merge the PR to the main branch and delete the original.
The problem is that the GitHub PR remembers the commit history of the original branch, even though there is only a single commit to the main branch and the feature branch with the original commits was deleted. Considering how I work, this means that the merged PR shows a long list of commits with message of questionable utility, such as 'done', 'fixed', 'changes', 'typo', 'm', etc.
I could manually squash the feature branch history before creating the PR, but this seems like an unnecessary step when the whole point of the squash merge is to merge multiple commits into one.
Is there a way to make GitHub not remember or show the commits on the original, deleted branch in the merged PR after a squash merge? Or any commits before the PR was created?

Despite its name, this question is not a duplicate: How to clear out commit history when submiting a PR on GitHub?
A somewhat related question about closed PRs: Delete a closed pull request from GitHub


If your feature branch is not used by others, you could squash rebase its commits before merging into the main branch. It seems in fact the all these micro-commits are necessary only during your development on feature, and that once you're ready to squash merge, their history is not important anymore, since you want to see them as a single change. So, if you're the only one developing on feature, it could make sense to squash rebase first, force push to the remote, and then merge with a PR.

PRs are precisely how work on a feature is tracked, that's kinda the point. Anything that goes into that PR is now on the record. If you want to clean up what goes into that record, you got to clean it before pushing. Otherwise, do all your merges directly to HEAD bypassing the PR process.

@dani-vta That's precisely what I'd like to avoid having to do manually. Since the squash commit & delete branch is there, it would be nice if it would also produce a clean PR.

@JeffMercado One of the benefits of pushing after each commit is to be able to work on different PCs and to have an off-site backup of your work at all times. Of course, I could rebase and force push, but I don't see that as being a good way of working. The squash commit is otherwise quite a good feature.

@TrayMan It doesn't seem like a very expensive mid-step. All commits you're merging need to be squashed, the interactive rebase doesn't need to do specific operations for each commit. You either squash them all or nothing. But I understand that this might be a matter of points of view.

@TrayMan Sure, develop on the branch to your heart's content. Ultimately, the branch you use to create the PR with is all that really matters. When you're ready to create the PR, clean up your branch. Either squash the branch you have then push and merge that, or branch off that, squash and merge that new branch. Frankly, everyone ought to be cleaning up their branches anyway IMO.

@JeffMercado To me it seems to defeat the whole point of squash merge and delete, if you have to squash the commits manually anyway.

If you are the only one developing this branch and others aren’t checking out on their machines: you can use git commit --amend --no-edit with a commit with message “WIP". That’s like a pre-squash.

GitHub has the “Automatically delete head branches” option for PRs. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-the-automatic-deletion-of-branches
